# Access UI controls from separate class library

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dispatcher

my solutions contains a library called Manager (with one class called ProductionManager) as well as a WPF project in it.
I would like one method of the **ProductionManager class** to access a `UIcontrol` of the WPF, how can I do it?

To be more specific my `UI` there is a button and a `TextBox`. Pressing the button, I call a method from my library from which I would like to update the `TextBox` in the `UI` Window.

I know I should use the `Dispatcher` to do so but I cannot figure out how to set it up correctly. Can anyone help please?

Here the **MainWindow.xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFMainPanel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="btnRun" Content="Run" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="157,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnRun_Click"/>
        <TextBox Name="tbox_Data" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here the **MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
namespace WPFMainPanel
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ProductionManager myManager = ProductionManager.Instance;

        private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            myManager.DoSomethingElse();
        }
    }
}
```

and here my **ProductionManager class in my Manager Library**

```
namespace Manager
{
    public class ProductionManager
    {
        private static ProductionManager instance;

        private ProductionManager() { }

        public static ProductionManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ProductionManager();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public void DoSomethingElse()
        {
            // Change the Text Box Named tbox_Data from here
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What logic you would like to work on in `Dosomethingelse` method, it is not good practice to place logic related to UI controls in other libraries.

Comment: Hi Hari in the Dosomethingelse I wimply want to change the textbox.Text property to "Hello World". Bottom line I am trying to learn more about dispatcher basically with this simple app. Tanks

Comment: You can do this, `public void Dosomethingelse(Button dobject) {Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => dobject.Content = "Hello World"));}`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

in your `Dosomethingelse()`  method get a reference to your text box.

```
  public void Dosomethingelse(TextBox textBox,string yourText)
    {
        var myTextbox = textbox;
        mytextbox.text = yourText;
    }
```

now when you are calling the method from `MainWindows.xaml.cs` call like this,,

```
myManager.Dosomethingelse(tbox_data,stringYouWantToAdd);
```

Comment: I thought in doing this way, but if I do so, I would have to couple my library too closely with the WPF app. If I could instead call the Dispatcher of the UI from the library I could access any UI control without giving any reference to the single methods. I even thought in doing something like adding a public Window myWin to ProductionManager.cs. I could initialize myWin in MainWindow.xaml.cs immediately after the initiialize(); call. What do you think?

Comment: I think you should learn more about dispatcher. We use dispatcher to prioritize our tasks. This article will be helpful for you http://weblogs.asp.net/pawanmishra/understanding-dispatcher-in-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved!, I found this method from one of [iJay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1134291/ijay)s' answers.

First you must create a static variable of your MainWindow. So your library can access it. And you must create a string property to set the text of your textbox.Then in the set accessor of that property you can use dispatcher to change the text

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ProductionManager myManager;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myManager = new ProductionManager();
        window = this;
    }

    internal static MainWindow window;

    public string myString
    {
        get { return myTextBox.Text; }
          //this is where you change the text of your text box
        set { Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { myTextBox.Text = value; })); }
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myManager.DoSomething("Hello world");
    }
}
```

now edit your 'DoSomething()' method as the following,

```
 public void Dosomethingelse(string text)
{
    MainWindows.window.myString = text;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but while the WPF project in the solution reference to the library, my library does not reference to the WPF to avoid circular references. This means that MainWindows class is not recognized by the library. Were you able to fix that?

Comment: You can approach to this by using Action<T> but I don't know a way to do that using the dispatcher. Because simply you cant access the ui thread from your library class through UIs' dispatcher. because that dispatcher is owned by the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event system and the SynchronizationContext class, this way you don't need the extra libraries.

```
namespace Manager
{
    public class ProductionManager
    {
        private static ProductionManager instance;
        
        // Store the UI context
        private readonly SynchronizationContext _UIContext;
        
        // Define event handler signature
        public delegate void TextChangedHandler(object sender, TextEventArgs e);

        // Define the event to listen for in your MainWindow
        public event TextChangedHandler TextChangeEvent;

        private ProductionManager() 
        { 
            // Set the SynchronizationContext, make sure to call your Instance from the MainWindow
            _UIContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        }

        public static ProductionManager Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ProductionManager();
                }
                return instance;
            }
        }

        public void DoSomethingElse()
        {
            // Don't change the TextBox here send the event to the MainWindow instead
            // Use the SynchronizationContext to invoke the event
            _UIContext.Send(o => TextChangeEvent?.Invoke(this, new TextEventArgs("Hello World!"), null);
        }
    }
    // The TextEventArgs, change for your needs.
    public class TextEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public TextEventArgs(string text) : base()
        {
            Text = text;
        }

        public string Text { get; }
    }
}
```

Change your MainWindow

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ProductionManager myManager = ProductionManager.Instance;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Hookup the event listener
        myManager.TextChangeEvent += UpdateTextBox;
    }

    private void UpdateTextBox(object sender, TextEventArgs e)
    {
        // Finally handle your text change here
        tbox_Data.Text = e.Text;
    }

    private void btnRun_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myManager.DoSomethingElse();
    }
}
```